# Looping through array and adding object to scene for each entry adds objects to the same position

Tags: three.js, virtual-reality

I'm trying to add an object to my three.js scene for each item in an array. I can't tell if all of the object are adding to the scene because they are adding to the same position, and I can't figure out how to change the position of each object.

Here is the code looping and adding a cube for each item in array:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

getData()
async function getData() {
    const response = await fetch('/api/indexvr');
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data)

    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        try {
        scene.add( cube );
        // cube.position.y = i //1++
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    }
}   

camera.position.z = 5;
```

I've also tried declaring the cubes and their position in the for loop but that didn't work either. I need for all of the objects to be visible and for their positions to be dynamic depending on the amount in the array, e.g. something like a circle around the camera and if there are more than 10/15, increase the y axis by 4 and continue the circle again.. I can't figure out how or find documentation to help. Any ideas or links to help? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: 
the cubes now look like this with the code received from Mugen87. 
[image]

Comment: You need to create a new Mesh for each thing you want to display. In other words if you want to see 10 cubes on the screen then you need to call `new THREE.Mesh(...)` 10 times and add each of them to the scene.

Comment: So there's no way at all of adding the mesh by iterating over a for loop or for each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like so (implements the feedback if @gman):

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );

getData()
async function getData() {
    const response = await fetch('/api/indexvr');
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data)

    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {

        var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        cube.position.y = i;
        scene.add( cube );

    }
}   

camera.position.z = 5;
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added an image of what your code produced. Every time I try to seperate them I get errors. Three.js is not forgiving.

Comment: What do you mean with "getting errors"? Can you please post the error message? Or maybe demonstrate the issue with this live example? https://jsfiddle.net/antmLfuq/

Comment: There's no longer errors, I was multiplying 'i' incorrectly. This is my code but it wont work in the code pen you send https://jsfiddle.net/dp26z3ba/

I've added another image of what the cubes look like now. They just don't look at all presentable but are getting better